# API code works in Angular but not in Ionic

Tags: angular, api, ionic3

I got the below API to connect the application to zoho creator

```
 <form method="POST" action="https://creator.zoho.com/api/batool4/xml/myapp/form/form1/record/add">
<input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="14e8d1c6acf83682cd9622986f0f7999">
<input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
<input type="text" name="Phone">
<input type="text" name="Date_field" value="11-Nov-2011">
<input type="text" name="Name_field">    
<input type="submit" value="Add Record">
</form>
```

I have tried this code in Ionic but it did not work but once I tried it in Angular it works fine and it inserted the data. Can any one help how to make the code working for Ionic as well.

Comment: What is the error when run in ionic ?

Answer (score 0):

In angular and Ionic we don't use this way in forms , we extract the data from the form with two techniques with Reactive Forms or Tempalte Driven Forms and then make  a service that call this api and pass this data to it. 
Here you are a full example with forms like you want just fix things that matches yours : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-solution?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In the provided solution, it is using angular not ionic. It works for us once we use it like this as angular but once we apply it in ionic it does not work. Can you please help with the code for Ionic.

Comment: In Ionic you use the same code I think except the code in the component moved to Page and code in service moved to a Provider and It will work very well